# Webpack folder structure

Tags: webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to learn Webpack, so that I can implement it with my html project. I've some dumb questions but I'm very confused about them. I understand the work on scss, images etc etc. The problem is some developers are putting all the html files in the src folder and then pushing it to the dist folder with the build command(html-webpack-plugin). And some are manually keeping all html files in the dist folder rather than src folder. Can you please explain which is the best practice among them?

1. Where should I keep my html files? In src folder or dist folder?
2. What is the best practice for folder structure when I'm working with html and webpack?
3. If any backend developer work with my project then which folder he'll work on, src or dist?

My Project Structure

root
[image]

src folder
[image]

dist folder
[image]

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/
[image]

Thanks in advance
Have a great day!

Comment: `dist` is a build-artefact folder - it should _only_ ever contain output files (e.g. from `npm build`). It should also be excluded from source-control (i.e. in your `.gitignore` files). If anyone thinks they're meant to _store_ working files in there then _they're doing it wrong_.

Comment: Many many thanks for your reply @Dai. In that case can you please tell me, is it best practice to keep html in the src folder and after that moving them to the dist folder for the production?

Comment: You shouldn't "move" things into `dist` - you should have a build process which generates _new outputs_ and deposits them into that folder. Also, I can't speak for that "src" folder because I don't know anything about your project layout.

Comment: Please take a look, I modified my question. I didn't move things to the dist folder manually. When I run npm build command then ,,things moving automatically from the src folder to dist

Comment: What you're seeing isn't files being "moved" - they're being _built_. If the files were being _moved_ then they wouldn't appear in the `src` directory anymore.

Comment: Yes sir, you're right. Webpack generating them from the src folder and they are working perfectly. Is this the best approach?

Comment: It's not the "best" approach: it's the _only_ approach. That's exactly how JS tooling works.

Comment: Thank you sir. So should I follow this?  One more thing sir, do frontend developers structure look likes mine, whom are working with webpack? or can you please suggest me any pre made structure that developers follow along. Thank you

Comment: Everything you've asked so-far is answered in [The Webpack Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)... - for example, the `dist` directory is covered [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/)

Comment: Many many thanks sir for your help. I got it. But still there is a little bit confusion. Why they create index.html in the dist folder,, why not in the src folder? Can you please explain it? I modified again my question. Please help me to get rid of the confusion. Thank you

Comment: The "Getting Started" page explains why they have `index.html` in `dist`: it's for the purposes of the tutorial. It's not something you should do for real-world usage. See the "Creating a bundle" heading, they write: "_You may have noticed that `index.html` was created manually, even though it is now placed in the `dist` directory. Later on in another guide, we will generate `index.html` rather than edit it manually. Once this is done, it should be safe to empty the `dist` directory and to regenerate all the files within it._"

Comment: Many many thanks sir for your patience. Now I'm clear about it. Have a great day sir

Comment: I've been awake 36 hours

Comment: I saw your profile, You're really genius. Many many thanks